# ng bind html contents with inline width

Tags: bootstrap-modal, angularjs-bootstrap

I was using the bootstrap directives for angular http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and I basically had a modal for which the body content is given by

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div ng-bind-html="render">
  </div>
<div class="modal-footer">
```

and in the controller I am specifying

```
$scope.render=$sce.trustAsHtml(data.html);
```

Here data.html has html content of a different website . The modal was working like I wanted 
and Html content was shown in the modal . The only problem was the html content of the website had some images width set inline like 600px or more and for this reason those images 
are not contained in the modal . It is crossing the border of the modal which makes it dirty . Is it possible to correct it ?? Please Help ...